# How to check if a shell command exists

Tags: vimscript

I'm now using

```
silent! let l:status = system(l:command . ' > /dev/null')

if match(l:status, '\cunknown') != -1 || match(l:status, '\cnot') != -1
    echo 'command not found'
    return 0`enter code here`
endif
```

i know it's not complete but is there any better way to check?

#### edit

i'm now using

```
silent! let l:status = system('which espeak')

if l:status !~ '\w\+'
    echo 'command not found'
    return 0
endif
```

#### edit

changed from `which` to `command` https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then

Comment: In bash, my standard is `command -v <command name> >/dev/null` and check the exit code.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble is `which` better? i'm using fish and i just fund `command -v` in bash is `command -s` in fish, but `which` is all the same

Comment: `which` only works on external utilities, so not shell builtins.

Comment: @wengwengweng https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then

Comment: @wengwengweng if the solution you found is satisfying you can answer your own question (instead of editing it), that will make it more useful and easier to read for future users with the same question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Incidentally vim has a special function just for this: [`executable()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#executable()).

Answer (score 2):

thanks for the comments above, i'm using this code right now:

```
silent! let l:status = system('command -v ' . l:cmd)

if l:status !~ '\w\+'
    echo 'command not found'
    return -1
endif
```